# flume+kafka+storm lost messages. Storm Topology messages will be dropped

Tags: apache-storm

When Storm Topology startup in a distribution cluster, I found netty connection will failed and messages will be dropped by client itself.

Worker log info as following :

```
2016-08-02T11:00:11.408+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection to Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702 is unavailable
2016-08-02T11:00:11.408+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] dropping 1 message(s) destined for Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702
2016-08-02T11:00:11.408+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection to Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702 is unavailable
2016-08-02T11:00:11.408+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] dropping 1 message(s) destined for Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702
2016-08-02T11:00:11.408+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection to Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702 is unavailable
2016-08-02T11:00:11.408+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] dropping 1 message(s) destined for Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702
2016-08-02T11:00:11.408+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection to Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702 is unavailable
2016-08-02T11:00:11.408+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] dropping 1 message(s) destined for Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702
2016-08-02T11:00:11.408+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection to Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702 is unavailable
2016-08-02T11:00:11.408+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] dropping 2 message(s) destined for Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702
2016-08-02T11:00:11.409+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection to Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702 is unavailable
2016-08-02T11:00:11.409+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] dropping 1 message(s) destined for Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702
2016-08-02T11:00:11.410+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection to Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702 is unavailable
2016-08-02T11:00:11.410+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] dropping 1 message(s) destined for Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702
2016-08-02T11:00:11.411+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection to Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702 is unavailable
2016-08-02T11:00:11.411+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] dropping 1 message(s) destined for Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702
2016-08-02T11:00:11.411+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection to Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702 is unavailable
2016-08-02T11:00:11.411+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] dropping 1 message(s) destined for Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702
2016-08-02T11:00:11.658+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 201 to Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2016-08-02T11:00:12.401+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 202 to Netty-Client-h040.kt/192.168.18.40:6702 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
```

Comment: storm issue :  0.9.5

Comment: I have the same in Storm V2.2.0